# Android Studio 3.1.3 : android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: java, android, html

I keep getting this error log and I don't know how to solve it. The error is a log from an emulated Android phone with 6.0 android version. I think the problem is something related to the Drawable that I just added (those are the Facebook, Twitter and Google+ icons). When the phone try to open the app, it crash.

I'll post the relevant information but you can find the project here:

https://github.com/Romeorubiko/Debtor

This is the error log:

```
07-02 13:33:17.474 7317-7317/com.apkproject.debtor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.apkproject.debtor, PID: 7317
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.apkproject.debtor/com.apkproject.debtor.ui.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.apkproject.debtor.ui.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:70)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.apkproject.debtor.ui.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:70) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.apkproject.debtor.ui.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:70) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File or from drawable resource ID #0x7f0c0043
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2640)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:230)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:199)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:195)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.apkproject.debtor.ui.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:70) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: or
    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:405)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2633)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540) 
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870) 
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:230) 
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:199) 
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:195) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.apkproject.debtor.ui.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:70) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This is my build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.apkproject.debtor"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:divider="@string/or"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:tag="@string/or"
tools:context=".ui.LoginActivity">

<!-- Login progress -->
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/login_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/prompt_email" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="6"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/prompt_email" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/action_sign_in_short"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login_new_account_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:contextClickable="true"
            android:text="@string/dont_have_an_account"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="@string/or"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/tvText"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tvText"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/other_sign_in"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="-12dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_facebook_sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorFacebook"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_facebook"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:text="@string/Sign_in_facebook"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_twitter_sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorTwitter"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_twitter"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:text="@string/Sign_in_twitter"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_google_sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorGoogle"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_googleplus"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:text="@string/Sign_in_google"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the parent `LinearLayout`. You would need add  in the end of the layout file.

```
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: my bad. I post it wrong. There is a LinearLayout close

Comment: Is android studio showing anything in red to indicate an error.? Can you paste the screenshot of the layout file

Answer (score 0):

It's unable to find a resource, I guess it's the drawable on the facebook button "ic_facebook". If you are sure the drawable is present try invalidating caches and rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figure it out. i just deleted 
   `android:divider="@string/or"`